# Stuck with cascading dropdownlist asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Hi guys im trying to make a cascading dropdownlist in razor pages with postgresql. The first dropdown shows the location, and the second shows the room of the location, depending which location you click. Im stuck, i dont know how to go further. I hope you guys can help.
Here is the html code:

```
<td>Select location</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="locations" name="Location">
                                            @foreach(var reservations in @Model.PopulateReservations())
                                            {                                        
                                                <option>@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.LocationName)</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>
                                <td>Select Room</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="rooms" name="Room">
                                            @foreach(var reservations in @Model.ShowRoom())
                                            {
                                               <option>@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.RoomName)</option>
                                                 
                                            }
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>
```

Here are the two functions used for showing location and room:

```
public List<WorkspaceModel> PopulateReservations()
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select DISTINCT location FROM workspaces";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { LocationName = dr["location"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


            return res;
        }

        public List<WorkspaceModel> ShowRoom()
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select room FROM workspaces";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = dr["room"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


            return res;
        }
```

Here is the model for the workspace

```
public class WorkspaceModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string RoomName { get; set; } 
        [BindProperty]
        public int SquareMeters { get; set; } = 1;
        [BindProperty]
        public int Lengthws { get; set; } = 1;
        [BindProperty]
        public int Widthws { get; set; } = 1;
        [BindProperty]
        public int Id {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: To know more about cascading in asp.net core you may refer this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it with ajax. Below is a simple demo:

Index.cshtml:

```
<td>Select location</td>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="locations" name="Location">
        <option>-Select Location-</option>
        @foreach (var reservations in @Model.PopulateReservations())
        {
            <option value="@reservations.LocationName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.LocationName)</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<td>Select Room</td>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="rooms" name="Room">
        <option>-Select Room-</option>
        @foreach (var reservations in @Model.ShowRoom())
        {
            <option value="@reservations.RoomName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.RoomName)</option>

        }
    </select>
</div>

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $("#locations").on("change", function () {
        var location = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/Index?handler=GetLocationRoom',
            data: {Location: location },
            success: function (res) {
                $("#rooms").empty();
                var htmlString = "";
                $.each(res, function (k, v) {
                    htmlString += "<option value='" + v.roomName + "'>" + v.roomName + "</option>";
                });
                $("#rooms").append(htmlString);
            }

        })
    })
</script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }

    public IActionResult OnGetGetLocationRoom(string Location)
    {

        List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();

        if (Location == "A")
        {
            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "A1" });
            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "A2" });
        }
        if (Location == "B")
        {
            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "B1" });
            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "B2" });
        }
        if (Location == "C")
        {
            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "C1" });
            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "C2" });
        }
        return new JsonResult(res);
    }

    public List<WorkspaceModel> PopulateReservations()
    {
        List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>()
        { 
            new WorkspaceModel { LocationName = "A"},
            new WorkspaceModel { LocationName = "B"},
            new WorkspaceModel { LocationName = "C"}
        };
        return res;
    }

    public List<WorkspaceModel> ShowRoom()
    {
        List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>()
        {
            new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "A1"},
            new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "A2"},
            new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "B1"},
            new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "B2"},
            new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "C1"},
            new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "C2"}
        };
        return res;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for solution i understand the logic but i couldn't get it work with my database. I'm not allowed to do hardcoding

Comment: Hi @anonD, it is just a simple example. if your data is from database, like the code above, you just need to get the location name in the `GetLocationRoom` then select the corresponding rooms from the database with the sql like `Select room FROM workspaces WHERE location = XXX `

Comment: Hi @anonD, if it is helpful, could you please mark it as answer, thanks!